# How do I know the percentage actually went down from month to month with different totals?

Tags: normalization, percentage

I have a production process, and I can measure the % of total defects every month and I know the granular breakdown of the defects A, B, C. I want to compare the breakdown of the defects A,B,C for two months to see whether it actually went down, how do I normalize the data to see whether defect A actually decreased relative to the total?

e.g., this is my data:

April 2022, %total defects=6.30%, # of defects=227, total number of observations= 2031: A=10%, B=10%, C=80%
June 2022, %total defects=5.00%, # of defects= 28, total number of observations= 560: A=5%, B=15%, C=85%

Comment: Do you have the actual counts, or just the proportions?  Proportions aren't very informative without the count.

Comment: You're giving conflicting information.  IN your comment, you give may 2022 but your question is about June.  Can you please:  Add the number of observations per month, the number of defects per month, and stratify those by A, B, C as needed?

Comment: I'm sorry, I deleted my comment. I meant this: I do have counts as well, April 2022, total number of defects=227, June 2022, total number of defects= 28